# Drawbacks of changing a standard voltage-current converter to amplify the signal?

Tags: current-source

I was wondering if there is any practical consequences on changing the standard Voltage to current converter configuration by adding a gain to it.

On picture I've uploaded, both circuits (standard on the left + an OPAMP with the same gain) has the same objectives and seem to work quite fine. I am just worried about implementing the second configuration and later finding a problem with the voltage-current circuit.

[image: Schematic showing a U/I converter with gain stage]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They both have similar compliance (very slightly more for #2)- they'll saturate at around 37mA.

The gain is a bit different between the two circuits.

Circuit #1 has a voltage gain of 3 and a sense resistor of 100 ohms so 1V in gives you 30mA current (minus a fraction of 1% for the transistor gain).

Circuit #2 will sink 31mA for 1V in (minus a fraction of 1% for the transistor gain). That's because the divider network loads the sense resistor, reducing the effective value to ~96.77 ohms.

Circuit #2 divides down the feedback signal so it may be noisier, all other things being equal (though the noise from the first op-amp may compensate if you don't filter it).

---

As an alternative, consider reducing the sense resistor to 33.3 ohms and scrapping the divider network. Then 1V in gives you 30mA. If the saturation at 37mA is desirable, add a suitable resistor to the collector side.

Normally the variable resistance load would be in the collector side (the 220 ohm resistor).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The resistor values, including 12V, were used just as an example. Im just concerned about not using the voltage-current standard topology. Both of them has a gain of 3 and they both work in simulation programs. This circuit will be used with a current-mirror circuit.

Comment: @TiagoC.M. One has a gain of 30mA/V and one has a gain of 31mA/V.